# Using Pandas query to filter out date range

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns as follows:

```
           Start    End Bucket
0   2021-06-30  2022-06-30  1
1   2022-06-30  2023-06-30  2
2   2023-06-30  2024-06-30  3
3   2024-06-30  2025-06-30  4
4   2025-06-30  2026-06-30  5
... ... ... ...
75  1996-06-30  1997-06-30  76
76  1997-06-30  1998-06-30  77
77  1998-06-30  1999-06-30  78
78  1999-06-30  2000-06-30  79
79  2000-06-30  2001-06-30  80
80 rows × 3 columns
```

I am trying to filter rows with a particular date if it lies between Start and End.

I am trying the following:

```
df.query(" '2021-07-30'  between Start and End ")
```

It gives me error

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    '2021-07-30'between Start and End
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alternative of between with `<=` and `>=` operators:

```
df.query("( Start <= '2021-07-30') & (End >= '2021-07-30')")
df.query("Start <= '2021-07-30' <= End")
```

Or:

```
d = '2021-07-30'
df = df.query(" (Start <= @d) & (End >= @d)")
df.query("Start <= @d <= End")
```

EDIT:

```
L = ['2021-07-30','2022-07-30']

dfs = [df.query("Start <= @d <= End") for d in L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jezrael. What if I want to check a list of values i.e multiple dates and assign them to their corresponding date buckets.

Comment: @Somanshu - What is output? List of DataFrames filterd by list of dates?

Comment: Yes......The output are the rows which satisfy the condition. I want to check against list of date values.